# How to pass a Request Body while doing a 307 Redirect with a POST Method and body from AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, post, redirect, lambda

I need to redirect to an another end point from my AWS Lambda function.
I have implemented the code below in AWS Lambda function and am trying to Redirect to an End Point implemented in an external system as a POST endpoint. I am not sure how to pass the Request Body.

Python code is trying to redirect, but I am not sure how to pass a "new" Request Body as it is a POST Endpoint, I don't want the original body to get transmitted.

Please see the Java error at the destination where it got redirected.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # Create Dictionary
    value = {
        "language": "python33",
        "greetings" : "Greetings... Hope you have been redirected"
    }
 
    # Dictionary to JSON Object using dumps() method
    # Return JSON Object
    return {
    "headers": {"Location": "http://localhost:8080/urlcallback",'Content-Type':'application/json' ,},
    'statusCode': 307,
    'body':  json.dumps(value)
    }
```

The Redirected End Point is getting invoked, but with the below error in the Java Spring boot logs:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1671820676750,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
    "message": "Required request body is missing: public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> my.sample.service.controller.PingController.urlcallback(java.lang.String)",
    "path": "/urlcallback"
}
```

I will greatly appreciate any suggestions or pointers,  I could not find any when I checked on Stack Overflow.

Note:

I tried first with basic redirect of 301 and 302, that works for a GET call, but now I get an error while doing a Redirect with POST end point and a request body as I have some sensitive data to transmit.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure how to pass a "new" Request Body as it is a POST Endpoint, I don't want the original body to get transmitted.

Based on [HTTP 307 docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307) this is not possible: "307 guarantees that the method and the body will not be changed when the redirected request is made"

You can try [HTTP 303](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303) and change the request type to GET to remove the body from the request.

Comment: Brian,   Thanks so much.  I verifed the behaviour and you are correct.  It is not possible to change the METHOD and BODY.  Also the  second idea of using 303 is not working either to use a GET, that is also retaining the method type and body.      Is there a work around if at all.    I want to pass this as body for security reasons.

Comment: I'm looking at the docs (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.4) and as far as I can tell the method body should be removed during a 303 redirect. Maybe your client doesn't honor this protocol for some reason?

Comment: Updating to let other users know.
I could not do a POST, but was able to manage with a workaround... 

    REDIRECT_URL="https://destination_react_server/" + jwt_Token222
    
    response = {
         "headers": {"Location": REDIRECT_URL, },
         "statusCode": 301,
        }
        
    return response

Answer (score 1):

Updating to let other users know.
I could not do a POST, but was able to manage with a workaround...

```
REDIRECT_URL="https://destination_react_server/" + jwt_Token222

response = {
        "headers": {"Location": REDIRECT_URL, },
        "statusCode": 301,
    }
    
return response
```